# Powershell to find Server Operating system

Tags: powershell, operating-system, find, windows-server

I had a task to find Operating System of all the servers we had in AD for some Microsoft Licenses requirement.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out.

Please feel free to use it and modify it. If you have questions, let me know.

It's a simple command. Hopefully, it helps someone. This gives you the type of operating systems you have. I am filtering based on Windows Server only and computer accounts that are active. Then sort by name and select unique OS.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*windows*server*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} -Properties OperatingSystem | Sort Name | select -Unique OperatingSystem
```

Output:

```
OperatingSystem
---------------
Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Evaluation
Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
```

Next command is to get all the servers and show their Operating System. Again, I am filtering based on Windows server OS and Active computer accounts. I am sorting my list by Operating system:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*windows*server*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} -Properties OperatingSystem | sort OperatingSystem | ft DNSHostName, OperatingSystem
```

You can also save the above in a variable and then get the count of Servers in each operating system category:

```
$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*windows*server*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} -Properties OperatingSystem | Sort Name

$servers | group operatingsystem
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$OSIs64BitArch = ([System.Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem)
$OSArchString = if ( $OSIs64BitArch ) {"x64"} else {"x86"}
$OSIsServerVersion = if ([Int]3 -eq [Int](Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).ProductType) {$True} else {$False}
$OSVerObjectCurrent = [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version
if ($OSVerObjectCurrent -ge (New-Object -TypeName System.Version -ArgumentList "6.1.0.0")) {
    if ($OSVerObjectCurrent -ge (New-Object -TypeName System.Version -ArgumentList "6.2.0.0")) {
        if ($OSVerObjectCurrent -ge (New-Object -TypeName System.Version -ArgumentList "6.3.0.0")) {
            if ($OSVerObjectCurrent -ge (New-Object -TypeName System.Version -ArgumentList "10.0.0.0")) {
                if ( $OSIsServerVersion ) {
                    Write-Output ('Windows Server 2016 ' + $OSArchString + " ... OR Above")
                } else {
                    Write-Output ('Windows 10 ' + $OSArchString + " ... OR Above")
                }
            } else {
                if ( $OSIsServerVersion ) {
                    Write-Output ('Windows Server 2012 R2 ' + $OSArchString)
                } else {
                    Write-Output ('Windows 8.1 ' + $OSArchString)
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ( $OSIsServerVersion ) {
                Write-Output ('Windows Server 2012 ' + $OSArchString)
            } else {
                Write-Output ('Windows 8 ' + $OSArchString)
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ( $OSIsServerVersion ) {
            Write-Output ('Windows Server 2008 R2 ' + $OSArchString)
        } else {
            Write-Output ('Windows 7 OR Windows 7-7601 SP1' + $OSArchString)
        }
    }
} else {
    Write-Output ('This version of Windows is not supported.')
}
```